# How not to let application exit when tasks are running

Tags: multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Is there any framework support for the cases when application is going to close but there are some not completed tasks?

Tasks run in the context of background thread by default. Sometimes it's ok just to let the task complete:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                          {
                              Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
                              Thread.Sleep(20000);
                              Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                          });
```

But this doesn't work if task has continuations which require completition. Especially if some of the tasks will run under UI thread.
It is possible to get all the "final" tasks and to postpone the application exit with `WhenAll()`.
Yet I do not know how to do the same when async/await is used.

So I'd like to know if there's any support for such cases. Are there any guarantees which framework gives or ways to enforce them?

The only way I see now is setting flags as a sign that critical tasks are not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you should not set `IsBackground` on a thread pool thread.

For `async` methods, ensure your methods are returning `Task` and not `void`, and then you can `await` them all using `WhenAll`. You can have your event handlers capture the top-level `Task`s rather than `await` them.

Comment: Could you eplain what is wrong with setting IsBackground to false?

Comment: But my task owns it exclusivly till the completition. And I set IsBackground = false only for that period. Do I miss something important?

Comment: You didn't create it; you don't own it. You're only renting it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646909/263693