# Why thread-pool doesn't complete task till end?

Tags: c#

I created very simple program and used Thread-pool for execute 3 task simultaneously. In this method 1 will print same message 9000 times (because using loop), method 2 and 3rd will print message 1 time. Now the problem is that, method 1 print message only few times and then program stop execution.
Some times not result display.

I know that if foreground thread will complete the task the all the background task will stop working. But how is it acceptable program stop working without completing task.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingInCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_1));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_2));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_3));
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
        }

        private static void Method_1(object obj)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's method 1");
            }
        }
        private static void Method_2(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's method 2");
        }
        private static void Method_3(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's method 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
```

That line will not do anything since there are no further instructions to wait for.

Simply add `Console.ReadLine()` and the end of Main.

```
static void Main()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_1));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_2));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_3));

    Console.Write("Press ENTER to quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you want to wait for all threads to complete, you can use thread synchronization objects like `ManualResetEvent`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingInCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        ManualResetEvent _method1Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ManualResetEvent _method2Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ManualResetEvent _method3Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_1));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_2));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Method_3));

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(new[]{_method1Event, _method2Event, _method3Event});
        }

        private static void Method_1(object obj)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's method 1");
            }

            _method1Event.Set();
        }

        private static void Method_2(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's method 2");

            _method2Event.Set();
        }

        private static void Method_3(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's method 3");

            _method3Event.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

`WaitHandle.WaitAll` will wait until all three events have been signaled (i.e. the methods have completed their work).

Comment: Setting IsBackground = false on a Thread Pool thread is generally bad idea. See explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646945/4544845

Comment: @felix-b: 1. That's why none of my examples include it. Read my answer again. 2. Neither I nor the OP did it on the thread pool...

Comment: Thanks Jgauffin, you solved my problem and i found the my mistake.